# Changing Principled BSDF default Surface settings

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to apply PBR texture (for instance from Polyhaven) to my properly subdivided plane. The usual way is creating new material and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd> having *Principled BSDF* active, so all maps are connected automatically into the nodes. And I'm always getting this flat result, even having displacement map connected

[image]

I found that by default there is *Bump Only* in my *Principled BSDF* settings

[image]

Changing it to *Displacement Only* or *Displacement and Bump* gives me this weird result

[image]

So I need to adjust my *Displacement scale* to an adequate value in order to get proper texture look

[image]

I have to do this every time with every new texture. Is there any way to get the proper result instantly? Is my texturing workflow wrong in any way? Or at least is there any way to change the defaults of *Principled BSDF* from *Bump Only* to *Displacement and Bump*?

Comment: AFAIK the displacement map contains value ranging from 0 to 1 because it can be applied to pretty much any form of geometry so you do have to indicate a range of values that corresponds to your actual project. The process in itself can be automated by python scripting but you won't be able to change this default behaviour without a bit of coding I'm afraid. Some settings are hardcoded and can't even be scripted.

Answer (score 0):

Open node_wrangler.py from your distributive (on Windows: `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\node_wrangler.py`) If you are doing it in Blender, you should run it as administrator to edit script file

Scroll to row 3297, it should contain "`# TODO Turn on true displacement in the material`"

After this row add:

```
               # TODO Turn on true displacement in the material
               # Too complicated for now

               disp_node.inputs["Scale"].default_value = 0.1
               if context.scene.render.engine == 'CYCLES':
                  context.object.active_material.cycles.displacement_method = 'BOTH'
```

Note that line offset is important, This should look like exactly like this:

[image]

Save the node_wrangler.py and restart Blender

**UPD**: I've found that it is really "Too complicated for now". Displacement method is set but isn't applied on object.

Comment: This just made my node wrangler stop to work. Neither Ctrl+T nor Ctrl+Shift+T work after adding that code

Comment: I suppose that you have broke something share the screenshot of the code

Comment: I dont know how to attach the screenshot in comments, but I've double checked the code and its the exact copy of your one with the proper line offsets. Something just doesn't work